# Is it possible to use regex with a custom table column of fields to search on another table? (SQL)

Tags: sql

This is a bit difficult to word, but here it goes:

I have a *very* long list of terms I'm searching for (>2K), which I'm planning to pop into my own custom table.

Is it possible to use regex to search for those terms in another table?  My company does not use a mainstream SQL language.

To illustrate, let's say I have a table **custom_keywords**

```
white
green
blue
yellow
```

I want to search for these in another table **main_table**, so something like:

```
 SELECT main_table_field
 FROM main_table
 WHERE REGEXP(main_table_field, '.*custom_keywords.*')
```

Where the output could be

```
 white shirt
 blue jeans
 yellow wall
 (etc.)
```

Is this possible??

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  "Not . . . a mainstream SQL language" doesn't give much guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 SELECT main_table_field
 FROM main_table mt
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM custom_keywords ck
               WHERE ck.keyword = mt.field
              );
```

Or:

```
 SELECT main_table_field
 FROM main_table mt
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM custom_keywords ck
               WHERE mt.field LIKE '%' || ck.keyword || '%'
              );
```

Performance will be awful.  The real solution is some form of text search with a full-text index (supported by most databases).

Comment: The first one worked absolutely brilliantly, thank you!!